# Is it possible to count inotifywait output?

Tags: linux

I am using Ubuntu 21.

I am using `inotifywait -m -r /dir/to/watch` to monitor the folder access and file deletion on realtime.

However, is it possible that I can have some kind of summary? For example, `inotifywait` will output:

```
/dir/to/watch DELETE deletedfile1.txt
/dir/to/watch DELETE deletedfile2.txt
/dir/to/watch DELETE deletedfile100.txt
```

Can I have a counter total how many files was deleted based on how many times `DELETE` occurs in the screen output?

Answer (score 0):

The `inotifywait` and `inotifywatch` commands are simplistic interfaces to the inotify API.     The first gives real time events.  The second counts events and gives a summary, either after a specified timeout, or on <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>

With the simplistic interface these two commands give, you have a choice of real time or summary with a count.  You can't have both, and any attempts to get both at once would need a much more complicated interface than provided by these CLI tools.

If these don't do what you want, your best bet is to write code that uses the inotify API directly.